# Conditional grouping clause (sqlite)

Tags: sql, sqlite, pdo, group-by, conditional-statements

Inside a `SELECT` statement, is it possible to `GROUP BY col_A` if `col_B = "some_value"`, otherwise `GROUP BY col_C` ? Then have that field that was used for grouping inside the results?

Like

```
SELECT value_of_the_column_used_for_group 
   FROM table WHERE ... 
   GROUP BY (IF col_B = "some_value" : col_A : ELSE : col_C)
   LIMIT 0, 20;
```

Basically I want to select children records that have distinct parents or parent records that have distinct IDs. But I want to select parent IDs, which can be the ID column or the "parent_ID" column from children records

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You, you can use a `case` statement:

```
SELECT (case when col_B = 'some_value' then col_A ELSE col_C end) 
FROM table WHERE ... 
GROUP BY (case when col_B = 'some_value' then col_A ELSE col_C end)
LIMIT 0, 20;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a name to your conditions and call after a while...

```
    SELECT (case when col_B = 'some_value' then col_A ELSE col_C end AS 'CONDITION')
    FROM table WHERE ...
    GROUP BY CONDITION
    LIMIT 0, 20;
```