# SQL: Number of times two items occur together in a join table

Tags: sql, sqlite

If have an SQL join table with two columns, for example called something like "Foods People Like":

PersonID | FoodID

1           1

1           2

2           1

2           2

3           3

4           3

4           1

PersonID, and FoodID both point to different tables where these values are the primary Key.

I'd like to get the count for the number of times two items appear together as foods. So, for example in the list I provided above, the combination of foods 1-2 would occur twice, while 1-3 would occur once.

Thanks for your help everyone. I am normally a pretty decent SQL guy, but this one has me stumped. This is in an SQLite DB.

Comment: Kindly post what you got so far.

Comment: I've been pretty far off. I am guessing I will need to add some kind of recursive inner join? select PermissionID, pid 
from overprivilege o
inner join permissions p on p.pid = o.permissionID
inner join (select count        ..... I know these column names are different, I was just trying to simplify things in my initial example.

Comment: Gordon Linoff has a very excellent answer. Try to check it out.

Comment: If a person has a combination `1, 2, 3`, should it count if you are looking for `1, 2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want pairs, then you can do this with a self-join and `group by`:

```
select pf1.foodid, pf2.foodid, count(*)
from personfoods pf1 join
     personfoods pf2
     on pf1.personid = pf2.personid and
        pf1.foodid < pf2.foodid
group by pf1.foodid, pf2.foodid;
```

This version assumes that there are no duplicate rows in the table.  If there are, you can use `count(distinct personid)` instead of `count(*)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional grouping, as below:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN FoodID <  PersonID THEN FoodID
        Else PersonID
    END FoodID,
    CASE 
        WHEN FoodID <  PersonID THEN PersonID
        Else FoodID
    END PersonID,
    count(*)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY
CASE 
    WHEN FoodID <  PersonID THEN FoodID
    Else PersonID
END,
CASE 
    WHEN FoodID <  PersonID THEN PersonID
    Else FoodID
END;
```

**Reference**:

[Conditional grouping clause (sqlite) on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471120/conditional-grouping-clause-sqlite)